# Extract a group of n numbers from a string in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of strings in a pandas dataframe that contains things like: `"AU/4347001"` but in addition there are other strings that are less organised, like `"Who would have thought this would be so 4347009 difficult"`

So ultimately, there is no coherent pattern to where and how these series of digits will appear in the string. They could be at the start, in the middle, or at the end, and there's no way of knowing exactly how many other characters are surrounding the digits.

Ideally, I would like to return another column of equal length containing only the digits.

Is this possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'text':["Who would have thought this would be so 4347009 difficult",
                          "24 is me"]})

df['new_col'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')

    text                                                new_col
0   Who would have thought this would be so 434700...   4347009
1   24 is me                                            24
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) with a capturing group for digits `(\d+)`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["AU/4347001",
        "Who would have thought this would be so 4347009 difficult",
        "Another with a no numbers",
        "131242143"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['txt'])
result = df.assign(res=df.txt.str.extract('(\d+)')).fillna('')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
                                                 txt        res
0                                         AU/4347001    4347001
1  Who would have thought this would be so 434700...    4347009
2                          Another with a no numbers           
3                                          131242143  131242143
```

Note, in the example above,  the use of [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill those columns where no groups of numbers where found, in this case, with the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's our test DataFrame:

```py
### Create an example Pandas Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['something123', 'some456thing', '789somthing', 
                        'Lots of numbers 82849585 make a long sentence'], columns = ['strings'])

### Create a function for identifying, joining and then turning the string to an integer
def get_numbers(string):
    return int(''.join([s for s in string if s.isdigit()]))

### Now lets apply the get_numbers function to the strings column
df.loc[:,'strings_wo_numbers'] = df.loc[:,'strings']apply(get_numbers)
```

**Note: This will concatenate all numbers in the string, i.e. "10 Olives and 5 apples" will turn into 105 not 10, 5.**

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.finall`

```
df.text.str.findall('\d+').str[0]
0    4347009
1         24
Name: text, dtype: object
```